# How to get Zend_http_cookie value into another function or page

Tags: zend-framework

I have the Following functions searchAction() and recentsearchAction(). I store my cookie value as $row which is an array variable. The problem is I want to get my cookies value in recentsearchAction() method. How to get it. pls help. I m completely new in Zend.

public function searchAction()
    {

```
    $form=new Application_Form_Search();               

    $this->view->form = $form;        

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){

        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();              

        if($form->isValid($formData)){

            $uname=$form->getValue('uname');                

            $search = new Application_Model_DbTable_Hobbies();

            $row=$search->searchHobby($uname);         

            $cookie = new Zend_Http_Cookie('cookiename',$row,'localhost',time() + 7200);           

            echo $cookie->getName();

            echo $cookie->getValue();

            echo $cookie->getDomain();

            echo $cookie->getPath();

            echo $cookie->getExpiryTime();                                

            $this->view->search=$row;                                                                                                 

        }
    }
}    

public function recentsearchAction()
{                

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$session=Zend_Session_Namespace("cookie");
$session->setExpirationSeconds(60);
$session->username;
$session->email;
```

Now you can use this session namespace in any page like:

```
$session=Zend_Session_Namespace("cookie");
echo "User Name : ".$session->username;
echo "Password : ".$session->email;
```

It will preserve you data for 60 seconds. You can provide as many as expiration time in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know to persist data in ZF is to dump that data into [Zend_Session_Namespace](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html), this will preserve the data until you unset it or overwrite it. Zend_session will accept string, objects and arrays.

basic usage:

```
//save data to namespace named cookie
$sesion = new Zend_Session_Namespace('cookie');
//namespace = cookie, data = cookieData
$session->cookieData = $cookieData;

//get data from namespace in another controller or action
//every time you need to access the namespace you have instantiate Zend_Session_Namespace
//I usually put a line in init() of each controller assigning it to a protected property
protected $_sesion = new Zend_Session_Namespace('cookie');
//access array or objects parts in session in normal ways
//assuming session is protected/private property
echo $this->_session->cookieData->username;//if object
echo $this->_session->cookieData['email'];//if array, I think
echo $this->_sesion->cookieData; //if single string
```

To unset data in Zend_Session_Namespace

```
Zend_Session::namespaceGet('cookie');
Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('cookie');
```

I usually cast arrays I want to store as objects `$data = (object)array('data')` to make access simpler.